# How do I include +1 Button to my website?

Tags: google-plus

I am creating my website in php. How do I include +1 Button to my website?

Comment: yes! What it should be then?

Comment: You should give explanation for your question here.

Answer (score 2):

Google has documentation for this (which I found by googling):

https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/

> The easiest method for including a +1 button on your page is to include the necessary JavaScript resource and to add a +1 button tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<g:plusone></g:plusone>
```

Other options are explained on the page I linked to.